# How would the following change using the bootstrap_form_for gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-form-helper

## I'm not sure how to re-write the :action=> tag in my old code snippet below to use the boostrap_form_for context. Can someone help?

```
        <%= form_tag(:action => 'attempt_login') do %>
         <%= error_messages_for(@user) %>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>email</th>
              <td><%= email_field_tag(:email) %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>password</th>
              <td><%= password_field_tag(:password) %></td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            <div class="frm-button">
                <td><%= submit_tag("login") %></td>
            </div>  
           <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `url: ''` instead. If you have problem finding the right url, run `rake routes` and search for your action in there.

You should have in your `routes.rb` something like:

```
match '/attempt_login', to: 'login_controller#attempt_login', via: :post
```

then edit your form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(url: '/attempt_login', method: :post) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But how does the url: '" bit work when specifying reference to an action that is a found in the user controller? Better yet, how do I specify the routes to it?  Currently my routes contain: match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)' , via: [:post, :get]

Comment: OK, awesome...Thanks for your help... I tried to vote up your answer but it's telling me I need a reputation of 15 to do it. I find this stackoverflow interface overly anal/restrictive.

Comment: You can just accept it, so it doesn't seem unanswered. No need to vote up. Glad I could help.